# Is there a way to get the positions of all clickable elment in Mac OS?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, api

For example, I'm in a Safari window, with menus and toolbars on top, and dock icons at bottom. All the icons and menus are clickable.

The questions are:

(1) Is there a way (API) in Mac OS to get the positions(x-y coordinate) of all these clickable elements?

(2) If not, is there a way to detect whether the current position of mouse is clickable? (In other words, is there a button, icon or any other clickable elements are hovered by the mouse now)

Does anyone have ideas about these? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious way is to use [OS X Accessibility API](https://developer.apple.com/librarY/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Accessibility/cocoaAXIntro/cocoaAXintro.html).

It's exactly what you need if you want to inspect elements on the screen in terms of functions instead of their graphics design.